# Prevent span4 from collapsing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with twitter bootstrap 2.x.x
I have 3 columns (span4) that I need to stay as that (3 columns) even when viewed on small screen (phone). In other words I need prevent span4 form  collapsing into 1 column, but still enjoy the responsiveness.

Thanks